# a way to make a backup of a wordpress website

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have a wordpress website that I maintained entirely through the wordpress admin dashboard. We don't use a staging server or FTP client etc.

I need to make some big upgrades to the the theme version and some plugin versions to fix some bugs.

Is there a way to back up the website or anyway that I can revert to the current setup before I proceed with this? Is there any tools or plugins that I can use for this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this plugin to have backup of your website. Good thing is, it takes backup of db as well. https://wordpress.org/plugins/backupwordpress/

Answer (score 0):

It would be risky on your end to make big upgrades without at least an FTP access, even if you have a backup plugin, when your website breaks up, you can't restore it anyways.

If you really need to do it, just do the updates in small increments, from small plugins to the biggest ones.